# Hexo Unhandled rejection TypeError \ Cannot read property 'each' of undefined

Tags: hexo

I'm attempting to use Hexo to make my own theme; I'm following this tutorial: http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/03/Create-an-Hexo-Theme-Part-1-Index/ but leaving out the Bootstrap parts (don't need Bootstrap atm) and I've encountered two errors which I don't know the origin/s of.

The error occurred when I tried running "hexo generate" after the "Read More" section of the tutorial. I found this: https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/1785 but its not in my language.

This is my theme's **_config.yml**

```
    menu:
  Home: /
  Archives: /archives

title: Hello Hexo
author: BH0

# Read More text
excerpt_link: Read More
```

**layout.ejs**

```
<html>
<!-- Head tag -->
<%- partial('_partial/head') %>
<body>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <%- partial('_partial/menu') %>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Blog Header: title and subtitle -->
        <%- partial('_partial/header') %>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
                <%- body %>
            </div>
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 blog-sidebar">
                <%- partial('_partial/sidebar') %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <%- partial('_partial/footer') %>
    <!-- After footer scripts -->
    <%- partial('_partial/after-footer') %>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.ejs**

```
<% page.posts.each(function(item) { %>
    <%- partial('_partial/article-excerpt', {item: item}) %>
<% }); %>
```

The error/s are:

```
$ hexo generate

Unhandled rejection TypeError: C:\Users\User\hexo_blog\username.github.io\themes\mytheme\layout\index.ejs:1
 >> 1| <% page.posts.each(function(item) { %>
    2|     <%- partial('_partial/article-excerpt', {item: item}) %>
    3| <% }); %>
    4|

Cannot read property 'each' of undefined
```

Thank-you, any help appreciated. Tell me if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments section of the tutorial: http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/03/Create-an-Hexo-Theme-Part-1-Index/

**"The error is normal and does not prevent you from running the index page of the blog. The reason it happens is because you have not yet created the rest of the pages, so as explained in the Basics of Hexo > page types section, hexo will use the index.ejs as a default for all the pages (including for example the post detail page). The thing is, not all pages have a page.posts variable. "**

I guess I got worried because the error / warning appeared in red (which I associated with errors) as opposed to orange / yellow (which I associated with warnings).